# find pages that have been 'redirected' on mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have many redirect pages on my wiki. They are hidden from the search by default, but I would like a way for an admin to see a list of them. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Why is this put on hold as “too broad”? Even including very far-fetched solutions, I can only think of three or so possible answers (use the dedicated special page, or the corresponding API call, make an sql query, or write your own extension).

Comment: I don't know. The correct answer was given below. Thanks leo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special page called `Special:ListRedirects` for that.

The list is limited to 1000 redirects, but some WikiMedia wikis can show up to [5000](https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aListRedirects&limit=500&offset=1000) results, so there seem exist some way around that limitation.